# Spamassassin+postfix issue

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I have migrated postfix entirely to another server and having issue trying to enable spamassassin.
After adding filtering to master.cf and restarting postfix no external (e.g. from outside domain) emails come through. For such messages there's error messages in mail.log:
relay=spamassassin, delay=4.1, delays=0.06/0/0/4, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied )

I tried to edit permissions for main.cf, even added spamd user to root group, but still no luck. Can anyone give me some advices what have I done wrong?
Thanks in advance.
P.S. On old server spamassassin works fine.